# antenna of the HC-06 bluetooth module

Tags: hc-06

Does the Bluetooth module HC-06 contains a built in antenna similar to HC-05 ?

and if so, then what is the benefit from using antenna?

Comment: Sure it also has a build in antenna. Mainly the HC-06 is just a HC-05 with different firmware. What do you mean with "benefit from using antenna"? As it is build in, you don't have a choice. Also every RF device needs some kind of antenna, or it just won't work

Comment: thank you @chrisl !